# How to read java class List from Vue Js

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js

I'm new to Front-end development, I want to know how can I read java class List using Vue.js.
I have this Java class that contain a list of fruits that I would like to read and display it in UI using Vue.js.:

```
public class MyClass {

    List<String> fruits= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("apple","banana","grapes"));
}
```

Comment: You can't "read" from a Java code. You need to create API interface in Java and request data from it using http calls from Front end to get the data from backend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you elaborate on the APIs i will need to create? or maybe do u have some example I can use?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use Java?

Comment: You need some kind of backend server to give you the data you need. Vue/JS will be running in the browser and it can't read data directly. Since you have Java code, you could try using backend frameworks like springboot to serve the data through API. You can read about REST APIs and how to create REST APIs in Java.

Comment: I'm familiar with REST APIs, I was just wandering if there is a easier way to read Java objects from same project.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Nashorn Javascript Engine in java 8+. With this engine, you can use it to communicate java with javascript.

Comment: Could you provide more information on how this would help the OP or anyone else with the same issue?

Comment: You can reference some docs. Example like: 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-nashorn
https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/